# Remove default route logging in Sinatra app

Tags: ruby, logging, sinatra

I have a Sintra app with a /health/api endpoint, described below, that gets called many times a second by my load balancers. I would like to remove the default logging for only this route, or conversely print to the logs only the endpoints I care about.

```
get '/health/api' do
  # Health Check
  'I keep quiet'
end

get '/members' do
  # get members data
  'This request gets logged'
end
```

Answer (score 8):

You cannot configure the default Rack::CommonLogger to print only some requests, and keep quiet on others. But you can disable the default CommonLogger and use your own with filtering capabilities instead:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rack'
require 'sinatra'

LOGGING_BLACKLIST = ['/health/api']

class FilteredCommonLogger < Rack::CommonLogger
  def call(env)
    if filter_log(env)
      # default CommonLogger behaviour: log and move on
      super
    else
      # pass request to next component without logging
      @app.call(env)
    end
  end

  # return true if request should be logged
  def filter_log(env)
    !LOGGING_BLACKLIST.include?(env['PATH_INFO'])
  end
end

disable :logging
use FilteredCommonLogger

get '/members' do
  # get members data
  'This request gets logged'
end

get '/health/api' do
  # Health Check
  'I keep quiet'
end
```

You can obviously also write your custom logger that only logs "whitelisted" requests.

Comment: +1 this is a complete solution for customizing sinatra's stdout logging.

Comment: I did `p t = env["PATH_INFO"] + ?? + env["QUERY_STRING"]; if t[/^\/log\?/] ; @app.call env ; else ; super ; end` but somehow I still see: `naki-PC - - [17/Jul/2014:19:23:17 ╠юёъютёъюх тЁхь  (чшьр)] "GET /log?position=2240 HTTP/1.1" 200 2
http://localhost:8719/ -> /log?position=2240
"/log?position=2240"`